# Simple Haskell bind expression evaluation

Tags: haskell

Can anyone help me check if this is the right way to evaluate the expression:

```
  [1..2] >>= \n -> ['a', 'b'] >>= \ch -> return (n, ch)
= concat (map (\n -> ['a', 'b'] >>= \ch -> return (n, ch)) [1..2])
= concat [ ['a', 'b'] >>= \ch -> return (1, ch),
           ['a', 'b'] >>= \ch -> return (2, ch) ]
= concat [ concat (map (\ch -> return (1, ch)) ['a', 'b']),
           concat (map (\ch -> return (2, ch)) ['a', 'b']) ]
= concat [ concat [return (1, 'a'), return (1, 'b')],
           concat [return (2, 'a'), return (2, 'b')] ]
= concat [ concat [ [(1, 'a')], [(1, 'b')] ],
           concat [ [(2, 'a')], [(2, 'b')] ] ]
= concat [ [ (1, 'a'), (1, 'b') ],
           [ (2, 'a'), (2, 'b') ] ]
= [ (1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b') ]
```

Considering this is what lies behind the list comprehension `[(n, ch) | n <- [1..2], ch <- ['a', 'b']]`, am I doing something stupid here?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: But is this the most convenient way to evaluate it? It took me so long to write that down...

Comment: You are calculating the cartesian product of two lists, to which `liftM2 (,) [1,2] ['a', 'b']` or even `(,) <$> [1, 2] <*> "ab"` are shorter. In terms of computation, it may seem to you that if you can term rewrite your expression this much, it would cause a corresponding excess of computations, but I would not worry about that.

Comment: Define "convenient" and "evaluate". I mean -- a trained Haskeller can mentally skip most of these intermediate steps, but would you call that an "evaluation"? One can even mentally jump from the first step to the last... Your steps are nice to me since they expose how `>>=` is implemented in terms of `map` and `concat`.

Comment: @chi I was just wondering if I took a longer path by bracketing things the wrong way and evaluating them in the wrong order. It is confusing to see so many `>>=` and `->` at the same time. And I have no problem with `[1..2] >>= \n -> ['a', 'b']`.

Comment: You can possibly simplify things a bit if you start computing from the inner subexpression. I.e., first you can reduce `['a','b'] >>= \ch -> return (n, ch)` to `[(n, 'a'), (n, 'b')]` leaving `n` as a free variable. This could slightly reduce the visual noise in the next lines.